# Weird vertical lines with table

Tags: tables

Using the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage{ngerman} 
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Value A}&\textbf{Value B}&\textbf{Value C} \\
\hline 
\hline
\\ \( 1) & \( 17) & \( 98) \\ \\
\hline
\\ \( x = \frac{42}{5} \cdot x + n\) & \( y = \frac{17}{2} \cdot y + n\) & \( 0\) \\ \\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Stuff}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

Comment: And the question is? A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: That is a fair point Jubobs, thank you for editing my original post. I will keep in mind making it compilable in the future.

My question is how do I fix the horizontal lines? They aren't long enough to make a proper table.

Answer (score 5):

Don't do

```
\hline \\
```

as that generates a truncated line with only the cell in the first column, hence the missing line segments, just do

```
\\
```

If you want to space out the array, use `\arraystretch`.

Comment: turning "\\ \\ \hline \\" into "\\ \hline" has fixed the issue, thanks!

Comment: @user46794 [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 3):

Good style advice for tables is available in the [documentation for the `booktabs` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs).  Here it is strongly recommended not to use vertical rules, nor double horizontal rules.  Furthermore to provide bigger row spacing in the table you should adjust `\arraystretch` (which is a command containing a factor) rather than adding blank rows.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}   

\usepackage{ngerman} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
  \begin{center}
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
      \toprule
      Bereich (I) in Nm&Bereich (II) in Nm&Bereich (III) in Nm \\ 
      \midrule
      \( M_{t1} = 0\) & \( M_{t2} = 150\) & \( M_{t3} = 150\) \\ 
      \( M_{by1}(x) = \frac{450}{43} \cdot x + n\)
        & \( M_{by2}(x) = -\frac{450}{43} \cdot x + n\)
        & \( M_{by3}(x) = 0\) \\ 
      \( M_{bz1}(x) = \frac{65}{43} \cdot x + n\)
        & \( M_{bz2}(x) = -\frac{65}{43} \cdot x + n\)
        & \( M_{bz3}(x) = 0\) \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
  \caption{Momente \textit{abgelesen}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```